# Determine the parallelogram inscribed in a given ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

I've come up with a problem that I think might be of interest to some members of the MSE community.

Given the ellipse

$$ \dfrac{x^2}{15^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{7^2} = 1 $$

I want to determine the parallelogram(s) that are inscribed in this ellipse, such that

1. The acute angle between two adjacent sides of the parallelogram is, say, $60^\circ$.
2. The area of the parallelogram is, say, $70\%$ of the maximum possible area of a parallelogram inscribed in the given ellipse.

What is the procedure (algorithm) to follow in order to determine this parallelogram, and how many of these parallelograms are there?

For similar problems that I've come up recently check also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542188/determine-the-triangle-with-two-given-angles-inscribed-in-a-given-ellipse) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542186/determine-the-triangle-inscribed-in-a-given-ellipse)

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Did it come out of an application?

Comment: Is it even possible to get a solution to this problem, given the constraints?

Comment: @BrianTung No, I just came up with the problem on my own.

Comment: @Andrei Yes I think under certain conditions on the parameters of the problem, there will a solution.  Due to symmetry, solutions will come in pairs.

Comment: Just find a pair of conjugate diameter forming an angle of $60°$.

Comment: Begin by parameterizing your ellipse in the following way : $P_t(x=15 \cos t, y=7 \sin t)$. Take a chord joining $P_{t_1}$ and $P_{t_2}$. Let us consider the particular case of an inscribed **rectangle**. The other points of the parallelogram being $Q_{t_1}=-P_{t_1}$ and $Q_{t_2}=-P_{t_2}$, express the fact that the angle is $90°$ by writing that the dot product $\vec{P_1P_2}.\vec{P_1Q_2}$ is $0$.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Excellent remark ; but this kind of things are no longer taught...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I did not get your remark.  How do you use conjugate diameters to construct the parallelogram with the given specs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first of all that the lines connecting the midpoints of two opposite sides of an inscribed parallelogram are two conjugate diameters, because the tangents at the endpoints of a diameter are parallel to the other one. Hence the first step in the construction consists in drawing two conjugate diameters of the ellipse, forming an angle between them equal to the given angle between the sides of the parallelogram. With the given data, for instance, two endpoints of the conjugate diameters are:
$$
A=\left(\frac{15}{4} \sqrt{8+\frac{\sqrt{4069}}{11}},
\frac{7}{4} \sqrt{8-\frac{\sqrt{4069}}{11}}
\right);
\quad
B=\left(\frac{15}{4} \sqrt{8-\frac{\sqrt{4069}}{11}},
-\frac{7}{4} \sqrt{8+\frac{\sqrt{4069}}{11}}
\right).
$$
And of course a second pair of conjugate diameters can be obtained by reflecting these about the $x$ axis.

Now we must establish on semidiameter $OA$ (where $O$ is the center of the ellipse) the midpoint $P$ of a side of the inscribed parallelogram, taking into account the second condition: that its area must be a fraction $k$ ($k=70\%$ in your question) of the area of the largest inscribed parallelogram with the same angle. To this end we can transform the ellipse to a circle by a suitable dilation, remembering that conjugate diameters of the ellipse are transformed into perpendicular diameters of the circle. This works because the ratio of areas and parallelism of lines are invariant under a dilation.

Consider then a circle with two perpendicular radii $OA$ and $OB$, and a point $P$ on $OA$. The inscribed parallelogram having $P$ as a midpoint of a side, and its sides parallel to the above radii, is a rectangle, with sides $2rx$ (where $x=OP/OA$ and $r=OA=OB$) and $2r\sqrt{1-x^2}$. The area of the rectangle is then
$$
{\cal A}=4r^2x\sqrt{1-x^2}.
$$
It reaches its maximum value $2r^2$ for $x=1/\sqrt2$ (by AM-GM inequality), hence the value of $x$ can be found from the equation $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}=k$, leading to two solutions:
$$
x^2={1\pm\sqrt{1-k^2}\over2}.
$$
But $x$ is the same as the ratio $OP/OA$ in the ellipse: from the above solutions you can then construct $P$ and the desired parallelograms.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found an answer to my problem, and I verified it numerically and graphically.

Instead of starting from the ellipse and trying to fit a parallelogram to it, I started from a generic parallelogram with variable side lengths, fitted an ellipse to it, and then derived conditions on the side lengths to guarantee the two semi-axes of the given ellipse.

Specifically, starting from a square with vertices $(0,0), (1, 0), (1,1), (0, 1)$, it can be transformed into a parallelogram with sides $a$ and $b$ and making an angle $\theta$ between them by the linear transformation

$ T = \begin{bmatrix} a && b \cos \theta \\ 0 && b \sin \theta \end{bmatrix} $

After applying $T$ to the square we get our ellipse which we want to have semi-axes of lengths $a_e$ and $b_e$.

An ellipse passing through the original square vertices has the general equation

$ \dfrac{ (x - \frac{1}{2})^2 }{c^2 } + \dfrac{ (y - \frac{1}{2})^2 }{d^2} = 1 $

which can be written in compact form as

$ (r' - r'_0)^T Q' (r' - r'_0) = 1 $

where $r' = [x, y]^T $ and $r'_0 = [\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2}]^T $ and

$ Q' = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{c^2} && 0 \\ 0 && \frac{1}{d^2} \end{bmatrix} $

The constraint on $c$ and $d$ is that the ellipse passes through $(0,0)$ (all other vertices will produce the same constraint).  Substituting $(0,0)$, we get

$ \dfrac{1}{c^2} + \dfrac{1}{d^2} = 4 \hspace{20pt} (1) $

Now, applying $T$ to this ellipse, yields another ellipse, as follows.

$r'$ is mapped to $r$ the new coordinates by $ r = T r' $ which means that $r'= T^{-1} r $.  Substituting this into the equation of the ellipse, gives us

$ (T^{-1} r - r'_0 )^T Q' (T^{-1} r - r'_0) = 0 $

Simple manipulation, yields

$ (r - r_0)^T Q (r - r_0 ) = 1 $

where $r_0 = T r'_0 $ and $ Q = T^{-T} Q' T^{-1} $

Now we want the eigenvalues of $Q$ to be $\dfrac{1}{a_e^2} $ and $ \dfrac{1}{b_e^2} $, and this means that we want the eigenvalues of $Q^{-1}$ to be $a_e^2$ and $b_e^2$.

Now $Q^{-1} = T Q'^{-1} T^T $

And this evaluates to

$ Q^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix} a^2 c^2 + b^2 d^2 \cos^2 \theta && b^2 d^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \\ b^2 d^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta && b^2 d^2 \sin^2 \theta \end{bmatrix} $

Now we have the following the two relations between the trace and the determinant of $Q^{-1}$ and the sum and product of its eigenvalues.

$\text{Trace}(Q^{-1}) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = a_e^2 + b_e^2 $

$\det(Q^{-1}) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 = a_e^2 \ b_e^2 $

And this implies that

$ a^2 c^2 + b^2 d^2 = a_e^2 + b_e^2 \hspace{20pt}(2) $

and

$ (a^2 c^2 + b^2 d^2 \cos^2 \theta) (b^2 d^2 \sin^2 \theta) - (b^2 d^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta)^2 = a_e^2 b_e^2 $

Simiplifying the left hand side of the above, we obtain,

$ a^2 c^2 b^2 d^2 \sin^2 \theta = a_e^2 b_e^2$

Taking the square root, yields

$ a b c d \sin \theta = a_e b_e \hspace{20pt} (3)$

In addition to the above three equations $(1), (2), (3)$, we have the area of the parallelogram specified as $A_0$, and this relates to $a, b$ and $\theta$ by

$A_0 = a b \sin \theta \hspace{20pt} (4) $

Now we have $4$ equations in the $4$ unknowns $a,b,c,d$, and can be solved in two stages, as follows.  Using $(4)$ in $(3)$ yields

$ c d = \dfrac{a_e b_e }{A_0} \hspace{20pt} (5)$

Equations $(1)$ and $(5)$ can be easily solved for $c$ and $d$.  Then equations $(2)$ and $(4)$ can be solved for $a, b$.

Finally, we have to place the ellipse in its standard position (centered at the origin, with its major axis along the x-axis).  This can be done by performing eigen-decomposition of $Q$ into $Q = R D R^T $ (i.e. diagonalization), and then we apply a shift-then-rotate transformation to the ellipse and the parallelogram.

That is, map $r$ into $ R^{-1} (r - r_0) = R^T (r - r_0) $

As I mentioned above, I have verified this solution procedure with several examples and verified its validity in each case, by graphing the ellipse and its inscribed parallelogram.

Below are the **four** possible solutions for the parallelogram of angle $60^\circ$ and area-to-max-area ratio of $80 \%$ inscribed in an ellipse of semi-axes of $15$ and $7$.

[image]